# Java Web Start Application requires medium secuirity

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I just wrote an application using JWS. However, when I tried to access it over on a client computer over a network, it requires the Java Security Level to be set to minimum.

At this rate, each client will have to reduce the Java security levels on their computers. Is there a way to avoid this?

P.S I'm using Java 7 to run and I also use Netbeans to build the application

Comment: "... will have to reduce the Java security levels on their computers" - Some say Java has already done that. Are you code signing? If so, you might want to read [Java’s Losing Security Legacy](http://threatpost.com/javas-losing-security-legacy). If you are interested in client safety, then its recommended to *not* code sign. That way, you can't accidentally break out of the sandbox. But you have to live with the prompt.

Comment: I'm not code signing. I selected the unsigned option when performing clean and build

Answer (score 1):

> At this rate, each client will have to reduce the Java security levels on their computers. Is there a way to avoid this?

Digitally sign the code using a certificate from a Certification Authority (preferably one that is already in the Java 'trusted' key store).  This has been discussed many times in the past few months.

Security levels are now declared in the manifest of the Jar.